# I want to step down 120 Vac to use with a 12 V latching push-button switch, can I?

Tags: voltage, resistors, switches

I want to use a latching push-button switch, specifically the Ulincos U19C1. They are rated up to 5 A and 250 VAC, and the LED is rated for 5..12 V (from their website.)

According to the seller, if I use a 75 kohm 1/4 W resistor in series with the LED, I shouldn't have any problems. Does this sound right? I just wanted to verify.

(Edit) Never mind. The current rating on these switches is way to low anyway.

Comment: More information about the LED is required in order to know if that will give it enough current. It might need protection against high reverse voltage during the negative cycle of the AC.

Comment: In series with what? What's the voltage you want to connect to LED? Please link to button datasheet so we don't have to search for it.

Comment: Device rated for maximum voltage or current.

Comment: It sounds like you are considering powering the LED from a non-isolated supply so you also need to consider the insulation rating between the LED and any touch points.

Comment: @Tim is [U19C1SG Latching Push Button Switch Silver Stainless Steel Shell with Green LED for 19mm Hole](http://www.ulincos.com/product.php?id=93) the item you're asking about?

Comment: @Tim If you are using the switch for a device which runs on a lower voltage, you could use that lower voltage (possibly with another resistor to limit the current to 15 mA or less) for the LED.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's just an LED with a series resistor for 5 to 12V, then the suggested resistor might work. But it will flicker very noticeably.

But not all LEDs can handle the reverse voltage when the AC voltage goes negative. If it can't, then the LED may fail instantly.

It would be much better to use a bridge rectifier as well as the resistor.

Comment: what a bridge rectifier is made of?

Comment: @MissMulan Four rectifier diodes.  But you can also buy them ready made as a 4-pin package.